# When is redis pipeline exceute() method blocked?

Tags: python, redis

I implement a Redis wrapper class like below.

```
import redis
import threading
import time

class IntervalRedis(object):
    @classmethod
    def init(cls, interval=0.1, host='localhost', port=6379, db=0):
        cls._r = redis.Redis(host=host, port=port, db=db)
        cls.r = cls._r.pipeline()
        cls.t = threading.Thread(target=cls._intervalExecute)
        cls.interval = interval

        cls.t.start()  


    @classmethod
    def _intervalExecute(cls):

        while True:
            print "1"
            cls.r.execute()     # blocked at here after some loop cycle.
            print "2"
            time.sleep(cls.interval)
            print "3"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "start"
    IntervalRedis.init()
    count = 0

    while True:
        count+=1
        IntervalRedis.r.lpush("foo", count)
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if count == 10000000:
            break;

    print "end"
```

In the main statement, it accesses `redis pipline object` and run `lpush` commands, looping `while` statement.

But real execution on the commands is run in `_intervalExecute` at regular interval with `pipline execute()`.

I think it Must run by when `count` reachs 10000000.

However, When I run this code, it is blocked after some loop cycle.
(sometimes 3 cycles, sometimes 5 cycles randomly)

Could you suggest me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not safe to access the same Redis connection from different threads. Each thread is supposed to have its own connection to play with (or use a pool of connections).

In your example, you have two threads sharing the same pipeline and connection.

Comment: I saw `redis instance` is thread safety. this is the description I saw `Redis client instances can safely be shared between threads. Internally, connection instances are only retrieved from the connection pool during command execution, and returned to the pool directly after. Command execution never modifies state on the client instance.`

Comment: Yes, but does it extend to the pipeline object? Probably not.